# Integrating Enhanced Ecommerce with GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

In my current project requirement is to integrate enhanced eCommerce with GTM for tracking  product impressions, product clicks, viewing product details, adding a product to a shopping cart, initiating the checkout process, transactions, and refunds.

For the above requirement I have placed GTM Container script and dataLayer variable immediately after the body tag in the layout page.

```
<script> dataLayer=[]; </script>

<script> GTM Container script </script>
```

Created Tags,triggers and custom javascript in the GTM to pass the data to GA.

My question is, do I need to populate the `dataLayer` object on the individual pages in the code? 
Or can we straight away populate the `dataLayer` object in the GTM interface by writing the custom javascript?

And where can I see the complete data in the GA that the `dataLayer` object is carrying?

If we write a "one API for all" the requirement, how do I call individual script in the GTM??

Answer (score 0):

If the datalayer you are currently working on already has all the correct enhance eCommerce items listed you do not have to do a datalayer.push as the information is already there.

You need GTM in the  section, not just  did you install GTM as per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en)?

You can use custom JS in addition with a tag to do a datalayer.push on whatever pages require the additional product information. The tag is what you use to refrence the custom JS you have. The custom JS on it's own doesn't do a datalayer.push